# Why does classname$1.class generate in this situation?

Tags: java, compilation

I wrote the following code to implement the Singleton pattern:

```
public final class Test {
     static final class TestHolder {
         private static final Test INSTANCE = new Test();
     }     

     private Test() {}

     public static Test getInstance() {
         return TestHolder.INSTANCE;
     }
}
```

When I compile this file, it should generate Test.class and Test$TestHolder.class, but it also generates Test$1.class. This doesn't make sense. So why and how would this be?

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AnonymousInnerClass

Comment: @sircapsalot the question is *where is the anonymous class*.

Comment: This is the type of questions worth to upvote.

Comment: I don't get that `Test$1.class` file here (JDK 7 or 6). Does anyone else?

Comment: Yes, `javac 1.6.0_45` on my Mac creates it, and I've explained its purpose below.

Comment: Anyway, as weird as it gets, my compiler (Eclipse's JDT) does not generate it at all, no matter what compliance level is set (with `javap` I can clearly see the `Test` class being passed to the constructor).

Comment: Eclipse has its own compiler, and is free to implement this another way.

Comment: Yeah, Eclipse has Eclipse JDT as compiler. I wouldnt say it is free, as the JVM that will run its bytecode is the same that will run `javac`'s. This leads us to believe that the creation of `Test$1.class` is a design choice, not a workaround to a JVM limitation.

Comment: There are a couple of other obvious implementations: the compiler could add a factory method to `Test`, or it could make the private constructor package-protected instead. I think all of these implementations *do* have to work around the fundamental issue that a class can't access another class's private bits, and the JVM enforces that at runtime.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill what can I do to prevent compiler generating such class file? I make the Test constructor package scope, it doesn't work.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Both compilers generate a synthetic constructor with package-level visibility. The difference is that `javac`'s  uses `Test$1` as parameter and JDT uses `Test` as parameter. It is clear what it does with `Test$1` and when it creates it, but not *really* why. Btw, `TestHolder` never calls `Test$1`'s constructor as your answer says.

Comment: @handrenliang Making `Test`'s constructor have package-level visibility will do the trick. You might need to clean your project to see `Test$1.class` gone.

Comment: @acdcjunior I have cleaned it before compiling. My compiler is 1.6.0_38

Comment: @acdcjunior sorry for my mistake. Package-level visibility works. I have another anomymous inner class.

Comment: @handrenliang I have 1.6.0_39 and this code does not generate a `Test$1.class`: `public final class Test {
     static final class TestHolder {
         private static final Test INSTANCE = new Test();
     }     

     Test() {}

     public static Test getInstance() {
         return TestHolder.INSTANCE;
     }

}`

Comment: @handrenliang Aw, ok :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Class `TestHolder` needs to call the private constructor in `Test`. But it's private, and can't actually be called from another class. So the compiler plays a trick. It *adds a new non-private constructor to `Test` which only it knows about!* That constructor takes an (unused) instance of this anonymous class `Test$1` -- which nobody knows exists. Then `TestHolder` creates an instance of `Test$1` and calls *that* constructor, which is accessible (it's default-protected.)

You can use `javap -c Test` (and `javap -c Test\$1`, and `javap -c Test\$TestHolder`) to see the code. It's quite clever, actually!

Comment: Decompiling the byte code supports this answer -`static INNERCLASS Test$1 Test null` is generated.

Comment: Great answer, clever implementation. Did you happen to know this off the top of your head?

Comment: @Vulcan, no, I did not. Thought it was an interesting question, compiled the code, checked it out with `javap`, and explained what I found.

Comment: Isn't should be `javap -c Test$1` and `javap -c Test$TestHolder` instead of `...\$...`?

Comment: Heh. The backslashes are needed on Unix-like systems, but not on Windows.

Comment: Thanks @ErnestFriedman-Hill. Your answer is greate. At First, I think classname$1.class will be generated only in the situation using anonymous inner class.

Comment: It also looks like you have to keep them in the same directory, otherwise your .class file without the $ symbol, will not work.